# How to seek to a particular item in list iterator

Tags: java, collections

I want to seek the list iterator to a particular position to move one from there.

I checked, If there anything available in the collections but I couldn't able to.

Below is the implementation I tried which works fine, but I would like to know If there any better way to do this.

```
class FileIterator implements ListIterator<String>{

        ListIterator<String> iterator = null;
        List<String> fileList;

        public FileIterator(List<String> fileList) {
            this.fileList=fileList;
            iterator=fileList.listIterator();
        }

        @Override
        public void add(String data) {
            iterator.add(data);         
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iterator.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasPrevious() {
            return iterator.hasPrevious();
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {
            return iterator.next();
        }

        @Override
        public int nextIndex() {
            return iterator.nextIndex();
        }

        @Override
        public String previous() {
            return iterator.previous();
        }

        @Override
        public int previousIndex() {
            return iterator.previousIndex();
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            iterator.remove();
        }

        @Override
        public void set(String data) {
            iterator.set(data);
        }

        public boolean seek(String data){
            iterator=fileList.listIterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                if(iterator.next().equals(data))
                    return true;
            }
            //gives the first element by default
            iterator=fileList.listIterator();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: _"but I couldn't able to"_ -- why not? What happened? Did you get an exception? If so post a complete stack trace.

Comment: @Boris the Spider: Thanks for the utility method. In regarding with resetting the iterator - its part of the functionality I am trying to achieve. Also the Iterators.find method is not working If I want to seek to the seek to some nth element when I have the iterator at n+m position.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. `Iterators.find` always works - it does what it says; if you want to search from the start, simply create a new `Iterator` from your `Iterable`; if you want to search from somewhere (your code doesn't support that either) then create an `Iterator` with `.listIterator(startIdx)` then use `find`. I would post this on Code Review to get some opinions on the logic and implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is

- List.indexOf
- List.listIterator(int index)

Both can combine to the desired functionality.

```
    public boolean seek(String data){
        int index = fileList.indexOf(data);
        iterator = fileList.listIterator(index == -1 ? 0 : index);
        return index != -1;
    }
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider one needs experience, trying things out. Having an iterator from a certain place in the list does not seem strange, hence listIterator(index). And a ListIterator has a bit of positioning power. The usage, creating a new Iterator internally is indeed weird. A `ListIteratorFrom(List list, T data)` would make more sence, but I almost suspect the list to be sorted too. A sublist, or stream?

Comment: @Joop Eggen: Thanks. It looks better than what I tried implementing. :)